# Top and Bottom bent borders

Tags: css, curve, css-shapes

I'm looking for a way to create bent top and bottom borders like the `div` in this image. I've tried some ways mentioned here but it depends on using white `div`s with `border-radius` on top of the main `div` but as you can see in this image it should be transparent to display the background image.

[image]

Comment: It will be better if you will create png image in phtoshop like same shape and set opacity something arround 70-75% and set it as background of div tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible using `svg`.

For responsiveness remove the `svg`'s `width` and `height` attributes, add `viewBox="0 0 400 150"` then try changing `#image`'s `width` and `height`, the `svg` will respond to its `width` and `height`.

[Demo on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/j8kudk9k/4/) demonstrating responsive shape.

<sup>**[Browser support for this approach](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg) - This will work on all browsers but IE8.**</sup>

```css
body {
  background: teal;
}
#image {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/300);
}
svg {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <svg width="400" height="150">
    <path opacity="0.6" fill="red" d="M0,10 Q0,0 10,0 Q195,40 390,0 Q400,0 400,10 Q390,75 400,140 Q400,150 390,150 Q195,100 10,150 Q0,150 0,140 Q10,75 0,10" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: but how to change the width and height? I've tried everything but it's not working http://jsfiddle.net/j8kudk9k/2/

Comment: @Yasser - What is your required width and height?

Comment: @Purag - [Check this out](http://dabblet.com/gist/e27eb4c9be480a0d3122). This will work on Chrome.

Comment: @Yasser - [Check out this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/j8kudk9k/3/). Change the `width` and `height` of `#image`, the shape's width and height will change as well.

Comment: working on chrome, width and height change without a problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Another posibility, not using clipping but multiple backgrounds.

Technically less advanced than chipChocolate answer, just providing an alternative

```
.test {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center -778px, 
        transparent 800px, rgba(255,0,0,0.4) 800px),
        radial-gradient(circle at center 828px, 
        transparent 800px, rgba(255,0,0,0.4) 800px);
    background-position: center top, center bottom;
    background-size: 100% 50%, 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Thw idea is to divide the element in 2 halves, and then set in each a radial gradient that matches the corners position. The final posiotion of the gradients adjusted by hand.

Can de done responsively also.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lew0grd/)

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/600/300);
}

.test {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center -778px, 
        transparent 800px, rgba(255,0,0,0.4) 801px),
        radial-gradient(circle at center 828px, 
        transparent 800px, rgba(255,0,0,0.4) 801px);
    background-position: center top, center bottom;
    background-size: 100% 50%, 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: jagged borders usually show when the 2 steps of the gradient are the same. I have increased in the snippet the second value, but there is still some jagg... just a matter of playing a little with the values, I think

Answer (score 2):

An other approach with one div, 2 pseudo elements , border-radius and box-shadows :

```css
div {
  width: 70%; height: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
div:before,div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%; width: 300%;
  left: -100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 140px red;
}
div:before {top: -146px;}
div:after {bottom: -146px;}


body {background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg');background-size: cover;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually doing this using the CSS would almost be impossible, and you would be good if you just try out a simple PNG image, created using Photoshop, Google Images etc, and create the image exactly of this size and then use it inside the website.

You can add the transparency to the image while creating it by using the Adobe UI tools for editing the image, or you can use the alpha filter in CSS to set the transparency effect to it to display the element that is residing behind it (the effect that you want).

Comment: @web-tiki's answer shows this is very much possible with css.